# Convert dd/mm/yyyy to DATETIME in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to convert a date in `dd/mm/yyyy` to `DATETIME` in a query. Here is what I have now:

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE start BETWEEN convert(datetime, '10/20/2015', 101) and convert(datetime, '11/07/2015', 101);
```

When I run this in my sql database, nothing happens. I don't get an error and I don't get a result. Is this a valid way to approach this?

I've seen this before:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '10/20/2015', 101);
```

Can I set this to a variable and add it to my query?

Comment: Have you seen the recommendations in the [MySQL reference here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) saying *"For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, cast the string to a DATE."* ?

Comment: You always delete questions lol?

Comment: This question is tagged with the mysql tag. Also the first comment mentions the mysql reference. But the convert function which is talked about in the question and both answeres has the synthax of the mssql server convert function... I think this question is about mssql and not mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion will not effect, because you converted in the same format `101`, and that will give you the same result. Please see conversion format here:

And base on your query , you don't need to include the hour, min, secs, and millisecs , because you are only comparing the two dates using `BETWEEN` , so you can use the `DATE` datatype only.

```
    BETWEEN convert(date, '10/20/2015') and convert(date, '11/07/2015');
```

If you want to format your date as `101` format , you need to convert it as `CHAR`, something like:

```
    SELECT CONVERT(char,'10/20/2015', 101)

    result: 10/20/2015
```

Comment: What if  `start` is a DATETIME?

Comment: There is no problem with that even if `start` is `datetime`. you dont need to format as `101` because you converted it as `datetime` , if you want to format the start as `101` , you need to convert it as `CHAR` not datetime.

Comment: I get: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `''10/20/2015') and convert(date, '11/07/2015')
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1` I am not putting that LIMIT part into my query.

Comment: @user081608 are you putting two quotes in `''10/20/2015'` like in your comment?

Comment: @user081608 , single quote only. `'10/20/2015'` , remove the excess single quote before 10

Answer (score 0):

Try converting `start` so it's definitely in the same format as your filter conditions.

`SELECT * from TABLE WHERE convert(datetime, start, 101) BETWEEN convert(datetime, '10/20/2015', 101) and convert(datetime, '11/07/2015', 101);`

Comment: I get this when I run it: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'start, 101) BETWEEN convert(datetime, '10/20/2015', 101) and convert(datetime, '' at line 1`